# Aitoc layered anvigation in 1-column layout

Tags: php, xml, magento, navigation, layered

I want to include Aitoc layered navigation pro to my 1-column layout on my magento site. I've been successful in adding the normal layered navigation by inserting this line of code in the content block catalog.xml

I thought that this would be enough to include the layered navigation pro, but this doesn't seem to be the case. Does anyone know how I can include this?

Answer (score 0):

Malte, are you trying to add layered navigation below the menu and above the content?
If you are, you can achieve this by changing the **Navigation Block** setting to **Top** in

`Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes -> 'attribute_name' -> Properties -> Frontend Properties`.